# Can I create a lifecycle rule to AWS S3 that moves objects that are already in GLACIER class to DEEP_ARCHIVE after 180 days?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-glacier

My company has probably close to a petabyte of data in s3 and we've been using S3's GLACIER class to get some cost savings. The files that are already in glacier were manually chosen to be put there instead of in the normal s3 class and thus there's no easy way to select them other than by class.

Is there a way I can add a lifecycle rule that filters only objects that are currently in the GLACIER storage class and moves them to DEEP_ARCHIVE?

Is there a way I can apply this to objects 1MB and larger through lifecycle rules?

Comment: Filtering can only be done on prefix and object tags. You might need your own nightly lambda to handle your specific lifecycle.

Comment: You can't do that with lifecycle rules, you'd have to write a lambda.